# How can I find papers of a specific journal?

Tags: research-process, google-scholar, scopus

I want to find papers of a specific journal. For example, I want to search papers about the smart grid security only in the IEEE Transactions on Smart Grid journal. Is there appropriate configuration criteria for the particular search in the Google Scholar or Scopus;

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try IEEE Explore ....

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102122/how-to-search-for-articles-from-a-specific-journal-in-google-scholar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the IEEE website and use the search they provide:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract those papers programmatically from Google Scholar in Python, you can do it using [Google Scholar Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-organic-results) from SerpApi, which is a paid API with a free plan of 100 searches to test out. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_scholar&q=%22hierarchical%20model%22%20site%3Asciencemag.org&hl=en).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scholar-Scrape-Papers-from-a-particual-journal?v=1) which will iterate over all available pages from Google Scholar and extract publication data (on replit, you have to pass your SerpApi API key in order to work):

[image]

```
import os, json
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl

params = {
    # os.getenv(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),                 # your Serpapi API key
    "engine": "google_scholar",                      # search engine
    "q": '"hierarchical model" site:sciencemag.org', # search query
    "hl": "en",                                      # language
    # "as_ylo": "2017",                              # from 2017
    # "as_yhi": "2021",                              # to 2021
    "start": "0"                                     # first page
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)         # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []

papers_is_present = True
while papers_is_present:
    results = search.get_dict()      # JSON -> Python dictionary

    for publication in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_number": results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}).get("current"),
            "result_type": publication.get("type"),
            "title": publication.get("title"),
            "link": publication.get("link"),
            "result_id": publication.get("result_id"),
            "summary": publication.get("publication_info").get("summary"),
            "snippet": publication.get("snippet"),
            })
             
        # paginates to the next page if the next page is present
        if "next" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}):
            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["serpapi_pagination"]["next"]).query)))
        else:
            papers_is_present = False

print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Outputs data from the one page as there's no pages for such search query:

```
[
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Pdf",
    "title": "Hierarchical Network with Label Embedding for Contextual Emotion Recognition",
    "link": "https://downloads.spj.sciencemag.org/research/2021/3067943.pdf",
    "result_id": "vuRtqci4UKYJ",
    "summary": "J Deng, F Ren - Research, 2021 - downloads.spj.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… In this paper, a hierarchical model with label embedding is … This paper explores a hierarchical model to learn contextual … (1) This paper proposes a hierarchical model to learn contextual …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Toroidal Magnetic Fields for Stable Plasma Confinement",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/160/3826/439.3.extract",
    "result_id": "kqZ_vhnt8KUJ",
    "summary": "DW Kerst - Science, 1968 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… The results of these studies are interpreted in terms of a hierarchical model of mental abilities going from associative learning to conceptual thinking, in which the development of lower …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Pdf",
    "title": "A high-throughput phenotyping pipeline for image processing and functional growth curve analysis",
    "link": "https://downloads.spj.sciencemag.org/plantphenomics/2020/7481687.pdf",
    "result_id": "093PpcXeoM8J",
    "summary": "R Wang, Y Qiu, Y Zhou, Z Liang… - Plant …, 2020 - downloads.spj.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… The hidden Markov random field (HMRF) model is a hierarchical model with an unobserved layer for the pixel class and an observed layer for the pixel intensity given its class. The …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Galactic Blowup",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/326/5950/206.2.abstract",
    "result_id": "WQd-NjqsznsJ",
    "summary": "M Cruz - Science, 2009 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… Fritz et al. show that a hierarchical model can be used to calculate the diffusion coefficients and excess chemical potentials (solubilities) for ethylbenzene diffusion in atactic polystyrene …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Microwave-Safe Dishes",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/326/5950/206.3.abstract",
    "result_id": "k-jOiH7l3-8J",
    "summary": "J Yeston - Science, 2009 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… Fritz et al. show that a hierarchical model can be used to calculate the diffusion coefficients and excess chemical potentials (solubilities) for ethylbenzene diffusion in atactic polystyrene …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Dissolute Behavior Up North",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/326/5950/206.1.abstract",
    "result_id": "5FXzkE1KrfUJ",
    "summary": "C Ash - Science, 2009 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… Fritz et al. show that a hierarchical model can be used to calculate the diffusion coefficients and excess chemical potentials (solubilities) for ethylbenzene diffusion in atactic polystyrene …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Embedded Sensors",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/326/5950/207.1.abstract",
    "result_id": "uJ2gwtehXzgJ",
    "summary": "LD Chong - Science, 2009 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… Fritz et al. show that a hierarchical model can be used to calculate the diffusion coefficients and excess chemical potentials (solubilities) for ethylbenzene diffusion in atactic polystyrene …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Citation",
    "title": "Pregnancy Can Be Stressful",
    "link": "https://science.sciencemag.org/content/326/5950/206.4.abstract",
    "result_id": "f6-h2PtpV_gJ",
    "summary": "BA Purnell - Science, 2009 - science.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "… Fritz et al. show that a hierarchical model can be used to calculate the diffusion coefficients and excess chemical potentials (solubilities) for ethylbenzene diffusion in atactic polystyrene …"
  },
  {
    "page_number": null,
    "result_type": "Pdf",
    "title": "Recent advancements in optical harmonic generation microscopy: Applications and perspectives",
    "link": "https://downloads.spj.sciencemag.org/bmef/2021/3973857.pdf",
    "result_id": "xHvS7epGUmsJ",
    "summary": "DS James, PJ Campagnola - BME Frontiers, 2021 - downloads.spj.sciencemag.org",
    "snippet": "Second harmonic generation (SHG) and third harmonic generation (THG) microscopies have emerged as powerful imaging modalities to examine structural properties of a wide range …"
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.